# Azure functions connecting flow to sharepoint with mfa

Tags: c#, azure, sharepoint, azure-functions

I am trying to use this tutorial: https://medium.com/plumsail/how-to-call-sharepoint-from-microsoft-flow-with-a-help-of-an-azure-function-a5740794341   to set up custom MS Flow triggers using Azure Functions to do stuff with sharepoint docs. So, I followed the tut exactly and only changed my credentials so far.

I get the following error telling me that the account is not authorized and I must first browse to the site and enable automatic login

```
2018-01-03T21:11:01.889 Exception while executing function: Functions.CreateFolder. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: One or more errors occurred. Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime: Cannot contact web site 'https://mysite.sharepoint.com/' or the web site does not support SharePoint Online credentials. The response status code is 'Unauthorized'. The response headers are 'X-SharePointHealthScore=0, X-MSDAVEXT_Error=917656; Access+denied.+Before+opening+files+in+this+location%2c+you+must+first+browse+to+the+web+site+and+select+the+option+to+login+automatically., SPRequestGuid=9c003d9e-9090-5000-1519-82d69fd4d838, request-id=9c003d9e-9090-5000-1519-82d69fd4d838, MS-CV=nj0AnJCQAFAVGYLWn9TYOA.0, Strict-Transport-Security=max-age=31536000, X-FRAME-OPTIONS=SAMEORIGIN, SPRequestDuration=29, SPIisLatency=0, MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices=16.0.0.7206, X-Content-Type-Options=nosniff, X-MS-InvokeApp=1; RequireReadOnly, Content-Length=0, Content-Type=text/plain; charset=utf-8, Date=Wed, 03 Jan 2018 21:11:01 GMT, P3P=CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI", Server=Microsoft-IIS/8.5, X-Powered-By=ASP.NET'.
```

Not really sure exactly what they mean there, but regardless my login requires mfa. Has anyone tried to do this before, is there something special I need to do when using mfa? Following is the few lines where client connection is made.

```
string userName = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SharePointUser", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
string password = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SharePointPassword", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);

var authenticationManager = new PnPAuthenticationManager();
var clientContext = authenticationManager.GetSharePointOnlineAuthenticatedContextTenant(sharePointSiteUrl, userName, password);
var pnpClientContext = PnPClientContext.ConvertFrom(clientContext);
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

edit:

Comment: I think the issue is because of MFA.  Is there an equivalent of [Service Principal user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/create-an-azure-service-principal-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest)  in sharepoint which could be used in automation tools given appropriate permissions?

Comment: We use AD to manage accounts, so I tried to make a SP user and then used that app id and secret with several auth manager methods. I gave the app Sharepoint permissions through AD -> app registrations -> required pemissions. I also tried just using app registrations to give the resource group containing my function and everything permission, used that app id/secret, used an app password. I now get forbidden instead of unauthorized, so I guess it's a permission issue but not sure what else I can do. Have you ever had done anything similar?

Comment: Using ServicePrincipalUser is the best way for automation tools. I would suggest try using SP credentials outside of Azure Functions first to make sure you get the permissions right.  Here is an example to [SP setup credentials](https://github.com/Azure/boilerplate-azurefunctions#2-set-up-credentials) that has right permissions in the resource group. Hope this helps.

Comment: Got it to work with the sp user, thanks for the info!

Comment: Great. Will move to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ServicePrincipalUser is the best way for automation tools. H

Instructions to set up service principal credentials

1. Get the Azure CLI

   `npm i -g azure-cli`
2. Login to Azure

   `azure login`

   This will give you a code and prompt you to visit [aka.ms/devicelogin](https://aka.ms/devicelogin). Provide the code and then login with your Azure identity (this may happen automatically if you're already logged in). You'll then be able to access your account via the CLI.
3. Get your subcription and tenant id

   `azure account show`

   Save the subcription and tenant id for later
4. Create a service principal for a given `<name>` and `<password>` and add contributor role.

   `azure ad sp create -n <name> -p <password>`

   This should return an object which has the `servicePrincipalNames` property on it and an ObjectId. Save the Object Id and one of the names in the array and the password you provided for later. If you need to look up your service principal later, you can use `azure ad sp -c <name>` where `<name>` is the name provided originally. Note that the `<name>` you provided is not the name you'll provide later, it is a name in the `servicePrincipalNames` array.

   Then grant the SP contributor access with the ObjectId

   `azure role assignment create --objectId <objectIDFromCreateStep> -o Contributor`

To make sure SP user has right permissions for the resources you need, try using it outside of Azure functions first.